# Using xsl:number with level="any" to obtain a more granular indication of node context

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am using xsl:number like this:

```
<xsl:number level="any" count="something" format="1" />
```

To get a number that corresponds to roughly the index of the current "something" node in the document.  This is helpful, but I need a more granular indication of where I am in the document.  I am using XSL 2.0 to create child documents and I'd like to have my numbering correspond to the subdocument.

So I am wondering if anyone has any experience using the count attribute on xsl:number with an XPATH, for instance, to accomplish this?  It would be great to specify a smarter count value that limited the scope of "something"s counted.

I can't seem to get an XPATH that works.  I am trying to limit the count to "something"s under a certain parent, where parent can be nested

```
 grandparent
           | 
           parent
                |
                something
                something
                something
                parent
                     |
                     something
                     something
```

So, I was hoping I could do something like:

```
count="ancestor::parent[1][child::something]"
```

In other words, the count of "Something"s under the current parent node.  I am not sure this is possible.  Ideas for an alternate approach definitely also welcome.

EDIT:
Just discovered the  "from" attribute. I think that might work.

SECOND EDIT:
I was able to get this working using Ian Roberts' suggestion with 'preceding::' instead of 'preceding-sibling'.  I will mark that answer as correct because it was very close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without `xsl:number` using

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor-or-self::something[1]/preceding-sibling::something) + 1"/>
```

i.e. the number of somethings before the one that the current node is under. Remove the +1 if you're happy for the first one to be numbered 0 rather than 1.

If the `something` elements are not all called the same name then you need to get a bit more creative, e.g. use `ancestor-or-self::*[parent::parent][1]` to get the nearest ancestor at the level *below* `parent`, whatever that ancestor may be called.

Comment: With xsl:number, though, I am getting a 'context count'... i.e. what is the index of the current something being processed.  I can see the same type thing working with preceding-sibling, but not all the way 'up the tree', right?

Answer (score 0):

Part of your textual description 'I am trying to limit the count to "something"s under a certain parent' sounds as if you simply want `<xsl:number level="single" count="something"/>`. If that does not do what you want then please provide a sample XML and the corresponding numbering you want to generate.